# How to filter index view with two select drop downs in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on, cocoon-gem

I want users to be able to filter through posts in my index view through the options in two drop downs.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<h1> Sort by 
    <select>
      <option value="newest">newest</option>
      <option value="popular">most popular</option>
      <option value="interest"> your interests</option>
    </select> 
  through 
    <select>
        <option value="all">all</option>
        <option value="tasks">tasks</option>
        <option value="feedback">feedback</option>
        <option value="investments">investments</option>
      </select>
   </h1>
```

I know I'm not using the Rails helpers, but it's because I don't understand how to use them in this context.

In the first drop down, the options are for different methods in the posts model (I put them here because without the params from the rails helpers, I don't know how to incorporate them into the index method in the controller).

```
def self.highest_voted
        self.order("cached_votes_score DESC")
    end

    def self.tailored_for_user
        @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC").tagged_with.current_user.tag_list
    end
```

In the second drop down, the options are the different post types which are, again, methods in the post model.

def self.show_feedback
            Post.joins(:feedbacks)
        end

```
    def self.show_crowdfunding
        Post.joins(:crowdfundings)
    end

    def self.show_task
        Post.joins(:ideas)
    end
```

I don't understand how to write the code I need in my view to make the posts render this way. Can someone start me off? I've spent so long on this issue and really would benefit from a second pair of eyes.

I am using the acts_as_taggable_on and acts_as_votable_on gems, as well as cocoon to build the nested attributes (feedbacks, crowdfundings, ideas).

Please let me know if I've been unclear in any way or am missing information.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding this: `collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial, prompt: true)` to your form. (But with your attributes obviously.) For more info: [collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select)

Comment: I think the problem with this answer is that I don't want to list an attribute like a name, I want to list a method. Do I have to create attributes for each method name and then list those?

Answer (score 0):

How are you sending the request to the backend?

You could create scopes for each option value and then chain them. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Then you can just do Post.investments.newest or whichever variant you need and you are done.